# Quotes all values of an array of objects

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have an array of objects

```
var obj = [{ key1: 1, key2: 2 }, { key1: 1, key2: 2 }];
```

How can I append quotes `"` to all values in the array of objects.

Result :

```
var obj = [{ key1: "1", key2: "2" }, { key1: "1", key2: "2", key3: "hello" }];
```

Comment: You don't want to "append quotes" to the values. You want to convert them to strings. Quotes are merely a lexical device to indicate string literals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could [**map**](http://underscorejs.org/#map) over the array and then use [**mapObject**](http://underscorejs.org/#mapObject) on each object in the array to convert the number to a string using [**toString**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString):

```
var result = _.map(obj, o => _.mapObject(o, value => value.toString()))
```

Or as torazaburo mentioned in the comment, use the [**String**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) constructor as the iteratee:

```
var result = _.map(obj, o => _.mapObject(o, String))
```

Comment: Or just `_.mapObject(o, String)`.